# Python how to replace sleep with wait

Tags: python, wait, sleep

I have a Python script where I would like to replace the sleep() with wait in order to interrupt the threads instantly even when they are sleeping.
However I don't know how to transform my functions into Events.
I read that asyncio could also be used but I am not sure to understand how it works.

Here is the code :

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import datetime
import time
import threading
import random
import pyautogui
from threading import Event

# --- functions ---
keyboardCtrl = Controller()

def run():

    print('Running thread')
    time.sleep(random.randrange(150,350)/1000)
    while running:
        my_keylist1=['e']
        while len(my_keylist1) > 0:
            n = random.choice(my_keylist1)
            keyboardCtrl.press(n)
            #print('Time:',datetime.datetime.now(),n)
            my_keylist1.remove(n)
            time.sleep(random.randrange(10200,10450)/1000)
    print('Exiting thread 1')
    
def run2():
    time.sleep(random.randrange(150,350)/1000)
    while running:
        pyautogui.keyDown('z') 
        #print('T2',datetime.datetime.now())
        #time.sleep(random.randrange(1000,3000)/1000)
        
    print('Exiting thread 2')
    pyautogui.keyUp('z') 
    
def run3():
    time.sleep(random.randrange(150,350)/1000)
    while running:
        my_keylist1=['f']
        while len(my_keylist1) > 0:
            n = random.choice(my_keylist1)
            keyboardCtrl.press(n)
            #print('Time:',datetime.datetime.now(),n)
            my_keylist1.remove(n)
            time.sleep(random.randrange(6250,6550)/1000)
    print('Exiting thread 3')    
    
    
def on_press(key):
    global running   # inform function that it has to assign value to external variable
    global clicker
    global clicker2,clicker3

    try:    # PEP8: don't put it in one line - it make code unreadable for human
        k = key.char
    except:
        k = key.name

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='q'):
        print("Key Pressed")

        if not running: # the same as `if running == False:`
            print("Starting thread")
            clicker = threading.Thread(target=run)
            clicker2 = threading.Thread(target=run2)
            clicker3 = threading.Thread(target=run3)
            running = True  # it has to be before `start()`
            clicker.start()
            clicker2.start()
            clicker3.start()
        else:
            print("Stopping thread")
            running = False  # it has to be before `join()`
            clicker.join()
            clicker2.join()
            clicker3.join()

    # press `F1` to exit
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        return False

# --- main ---

running = False  # default value at start

try:
    print("Starting program")
    print("- press E to start/stop thread")
    print("- press F1 to exit")
    print("- press Ctrl+C to exit")
    
    lis = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
    lis.start()
    print("Listening ...")
    
    lis.join()
    print("Exiting program")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stoped by Ctrl+C")
else:
    print("Stoped by F1")
finally:
    if running:
        running = False
        clicker.join()
        clicker2.join()
        clicker3.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like, I am sure there is a better solution, I would suggest reading the documentation.

```
import asyncio

from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import datetime
import time
import threading
import random
import pyautogui
from threading import Event

# --- functions ---
keyboardCtrl = Controller()

async def run():
    print('Running thread')

    await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(150, 350) / 1000)
    while running:
        my_keylist1 = ['e']
        while len(my_keylist1) > 0:
            n = random.choice(my_keylist1)
            keyboardCtrl.press(n)
            # print('Time:',datetime.datetime.now(),n)
            my_keylist1.remove(n)
            #time.sleep(random.randrange(10200, 10450) / 1000)
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(10200, 10450) / 1000)
    print('Exiting thread 1')


async def run2():
    #time.sleep(random.randrange(150, 350) / 1000)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(150, 350) / 1000)
    while running:
        pyautogui.keyDown('z')
        # print('T2',datetime.datetime.now())
        # time.sleep(random.randrange(1000,3000)/1000)

    print('Exiting thread 2')
    pyautogui.keyUp('z')


async def run3():
    #time.sleep(random.randrange(150, 350) / 1000)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(150, 350) / 1000)
    while running:
        my_keylist1 = ['f']
        while len(my_keylist1) > 0:
            n = random.choice(my_keylist1)
            keyboardCtrl.press(n)
            # print('Time:',datetime.datetime.now(),n)
            my_keylist1.remove(n)
            #time.sleep(random.randrange(6250, 6550) / 1000)
            await asyncio.sleep(random.randrange(6250, 6550) / 1000)
    print('Exiting thread 3')


async def on_press(key):
    global running  # inform function that it has to assign value to external variable
    global clicker
    global clicker2, clicker3

    try:  # PEP8: don't put it in one line - it make code unreadable for human
        k = key.char
    except:
        k = key.name

    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='q'):
        print("Key Pressed")

        if not running:  # the same as `if running == False:`
            print("Starting thread")
            #await run()
            #await run2()
            #await  run3()
            await asyncio.gather(*[run(), run2(), run3()])
            #clicker = threading.Thread(target=run)
            #clicker2 = threading.Thread(target=run2)
            #clicker3 = threading.Thread(target=run3)
            running = True  # it has to be before `start()`
            #clicker.start()
            #clicker2.start()
            #clicker3.start()
        else:
            print("Stopping thread")
            running = False  # it has to be before `join()`
            #clicker.join()
            #clicker2.join()
            #clicker3.join()

    # press `F1` to exit
    if key == keyboard.Key.f1:
        return False


# --- main ---

running = False  # default value at start

def main(*args, **kwargs):

    asyncio.run(on_press(args[0]))




try:
    print("Starting program")
    print("- press E to start/stop thread")
    print("- press F1 to exit")
    print("- press Ctrl+C to exit")

    lis = keyboard.Listener(on_press=main)
    lis.start()
    print("Listening ...")

    lis.join()
    print("Exiting program")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stoped by Ctrl+C")
else:
    print("Stoped by F1")
finally:
    if running:
        running = False
        #clicker.join()
        #clicker2.join()
        #clicker3.join()
```